# How to create a blank transparent png in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

How can I create a blank png UIImage in Objective C programmatically (let's say 36x36 px)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can open an image context, and then harvest its content immediately, without drawing anything into it. This should produce a blank `36x36` `UIImage`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(36, 36), NO, 0.0);
UIImage *blank = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let img = UIImage() // size does not matter for a blank transparent image
```

When using a blank transparent image, its size does not matter, and I think the `imageView.contentMode` might be any scalable value, or set it to `UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit` or `UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill` if needed.